Outlook for Mac: Shorter Meetings by Design (aka "Take 5")
I need help replicating a VBA macro for Outlook on Mac.
I've recently switched from PC to Mac for work. Previously, I used a VBA macro to start all my meetings 5 minutes late. This gives people a chance to take a comfort break before speaking to me; often people run from meetings back to back.
I would like all meetings to start 5 minutes late. This could be done by defaulting the starting time to xx:05 and xx:35. This could also be done by defining a keyboard shortcut, or adding an action button to the Outlook ribbon.
Sub latestart_meeting()
    Set objApp = Application

    Set MyMeeting = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    With MyMeeting

        .Duration = .Duration - 5
        .Start = DateAdd("n", 5, .Start)

    End With

End Sub

I've heard this can be done with Applescript, but I'm not familiar with it.
